# c# return data from Asynchronous function

Tags: c#, string, asynchronous, void

I have two methods

```
public void GetEmp()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new System.Uri("http://sdw2629/empservice/EmployeeInfo.svc/Employee"));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(ReadWebRequestCallback), request);  

}
```

and

```
private void ReadWebRequestCallback(IAsyncResult callbackResult)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)callbackResult.AsyncState;
    using (HttpWebResponse myResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.EndGetResponse(callbackResult))
    {
        using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
            //execute UI stuff on UI thread.              
        }
    }
}
```

Here i want to return a string "results" to some other method like this

```
string data= obj1.GetEmp()
```

How can i achieve this.. Any help would be appriciated.. Thanks

Comment: Why dont you use GetResponse() if you want a synchronous [blocking ] call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is rewrite method using `async`, like this:

```
public async Task<string> GetEmpAsync()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new System.Uri("http://sdw2629/empservice/EmployeeInfo.svc/Employee"));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
    using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string results = await httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        //execute UI stuff on UI thread.
        return results;
    }

}
```

Then you can get result with code like this:

```
var results = await GetEmpAsync();
```

If you are using older version and don't have `async`, you can do it in blocking way to get result:

```
public string GetEmpBlocking()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new System.Uri("http://sdw2629/empservice/EmployeeInfo.svc/Employee"));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    var response = request.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string results = httpwebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        //execute UI stuff on UI thread.
        return results;
    }
}
```

And get result like this:

```
var results = GetResultBlocking();
```

Р.S. you can also consider using [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) to support `async` in earlier versions.

Comment: at this line var results = await GetempAsync(); i am getting this error "MyClass' does not contain a definition for 'GetempAsync' and no extension method 'GetempAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'MyClass' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: @SagarJagadesh sorry there was a typo, there should be `var results = await GetEmpAsync();`. Basicaly it's just call of your method with `await` keyword before it.

Comment: Hi i am getting error as "Unknown identifier: request " at this line "await request.GetResponseAsync(); " can u please suggest ?

Comment: @SagarJagadesh what version of .Net are you using? If it's 4.5 or upper please check that you added 'async' to method definition. If it's less than 4.5 you need add `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` lib to support async.

Comment: i just replaced this line " var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();" with new line "var response = (HttpWebResponse) await request.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);".. Its working fine..Thanks for the help..

Answer (score 2):

Just use the

```
var resp = request.GetResponse();
```

instead of the

```
request.BeginGetResponse(...);
```

With the synchrounous GetResonse, you can return the string directly.

```
public string GetEmp()
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new System.Uri(@"http://.../data.json"));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

    var resp = request.GetResponse();

    using (var httpWebStreamReader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = httpWebStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        return result;
    }
}
```